# Customize an Eclipse formatter to remove unnecessary curly braces

Tags: java, eclipse, code-formatting

I would like to configure a formatter in Eclipse that removes curly braces when they surround a return/break/continue control statement:

```
if (x == y) {
    return true;
} //that's bad

if (x == y) return true; //that's better
```

I've found under `Preferences --> Java --> Code Style --> Formatter --> Control Statements` how to keep `if` and `else` statements on one line, but not how to get rid of the unnecessary braces. Does Eclipse let you define a formatter which eliminates redundant braces?

Comment: just a note: Sonar, a popular source code analyzer, favors the usage of curly braces for if/else/for/while/do statements. Removing them is not considered to be a good practice. Your code might get less lines, but it is not a good convention for many others.

Comment: Indentation and brace-placing debate is likely to trigger Religious Warfare, but I absolutely disagree with your assertion **//that's better**

Comment: For a very simple statement like `return true`, if you _really_ want to add something else there, what you probably should do most of the time (although contingent on circumstances) is enclose the whole thing in a `try` block and put the cleanup code you were going to add in the `finally`.

Answer (score 2):

**Preferences > Java > Code Style > Clean Up**, press Edit..., Code Style tab, set `Use blocks in if/while/for/do statements` to `Only if necessary`. After that you can simply do the hell on particular file or even whole project with Source > Clean Up... option :)

P.S. Nevertheless, my choice is "Always".

Answer (score 0):

Go to Java -> Editor -> Typing and see if that is what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

Formatters aren't supposed to change the non-whitespace characters.  What you're referring to would be a part of the **Clean Up** functionality, but I don't see exactly what you've mentioned as one of the things it can do.