# How can we remove brackets from single line for Java in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, formatting, coding-style

How can we **remove brackets/braces from a single line** for Java in Eclipse?

For example, I have code like these

```java
if (i < -1)
{
    System.out.println("Hello, Java!");
}
```

```java
if (i < -1) { System.out.println("Hello, Java!"); }
```

which Id like to become

```java
if (i < -1) System.out.println("Hello, Java!");
```

Comment: have you checked the settings of "Clean Up"  and "Formatter" (under "Code Styles")?

Comment: Check if this SO answer helps - https://stackoverflow.com/a/20024636/471467